# Why does localhost shows "It Works!" instead of my document?

Tags: apache, flutter, visual-studio-code, localhost

I've been recently looking into Flutter, and I wanted to try to start with a "Hello world.", I clicked Start Debugging in VSCode and it launched localhost in my browser. After a few seconds, it popped an HTML document saying "It Works!" instead of my program.

I'm currently using **Apache** `2.3.4` and the Flutter Extension is installed

Comment: Not clear if you were doing a flutter web build, or something else.  If doing a flutter web debug session, the browser should have been pointed toward your running app.  Apache generates "it works" as a default document, but Apache shouldn't have even been involved in this!

Comment: @RandalSchwartz then what do I need to do to run Flutter/Dart code?

Comment: Follow the documentation first: https://flutter.dev/web